# How to change AppBarButton circle and icon color windows phone 8.1 Page bottom bar

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to customize the circle and icon color of `AppBarButton` so far I tried following style but it does not work. In design mode it show circle color to green. But when I run the circle color is not changed what I am doing wrong here.

App bar button style

```
 <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent" Width="100">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,14,0,13" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="40">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="BackgroundEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="40" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="OutlineEllipse" Height="40" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="40"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

My Bottom bar xaml

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" Icon="Bookmarks"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" >
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept"></SymbolIcon>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do so on an individual basis. The app bar is system UI and doesn't support customised icon colours.

You can theme the entire app bar by setting the CommandBar.Foreground and .Background properties. The icons will all draw in the Foreground colour and the CommandBar itself in the Background colour:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Foreground="Cyan" Background="Magenta">
        <AppBarButton  Icon="Bookmarks"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton  >
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept"></SymbolIcon>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

If you really want individually customised buttons then you can't put them in an AppBar. Instead you can dock a small stackpanel at the bottom of the page and edit the AppBarButton's style to change the colour of the Ellipse (setting its Stroke to {TemplateBinding Foreground} will make it match the Foreground set in the AppBarButton)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <AppBarButton Foreground="Cyan" Icon="Bookmarks" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}"></AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Foreground="Magenta" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept"></SymbolIcon>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I don't recommend these colour combinations for anything other than demonstration: in a real app the colours should be drawn from a ThemeDictionary that falls back to defaults in high contrast themes.

Comment: Setting the CommandBar Foreground color does nothing to the AppBarButton, you have to set the AppBarButton colors individually. Things must have changed since you posted this answer. Also, you can now individually set colors in the CommandBar.