# AppBarButton theme in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, resources, winrt-xaml, winrt-component

I've tried to override default themes for AppBarItem and Keyboard, but still accent colors for application bar items remain default, resources that I've used are listed below. Is it possible to change in code the background of AppBarItem and the background of phone keyboard in pressed stated?

```
"PhoneAccentBrush",
"ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
"ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush",
"ProgressBarForegroundThemeBrush",
"ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush",
"SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush",
"CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
"AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush",
"AppBarBorderThemeBrush",
"AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush",
"AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush"
"AppBarItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush"
```

Comment: What helped me with AppBar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28355644/267000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this please :

in `App.xaml.cs` page :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TheRecourceKeyHere" Color="Magenta" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For more : [Overwrite Accent Color in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562483/overwrite-accent-color-in-app)

Comment: This helped to change for example PhoneAccentBrush, but still AppBarButton background in pressed stated has not changed.

Comment: You can overwrite the Style of AppBarButton  by Blend .. It'll solve your problem :)

Comment: There is the bug in WinRT, which I'll you later and which prevented me to override AppBarButton theme. Besides, I've known that it's not about AppBarButton style, it's rather CommandBar theming.

Comment: Aha, OK .. I think that I can't help any more :(